# Problem with discord embeds, and [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, es6-promise

I'm coding a discord bot, and I need to know who reacted to a specified message, and put they usernames in a discord embed.

Here's the code:

```
MSG.messages.fetch({ around: GameID, limit: 1 }).then((msg) => {
  fetchedMsg = msg.first();
  let MessageOBJ = fetchedMsg.reactions.cache.get("");

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("All players here !")
    .setDescription("Here's all of the players for this game")
    .addField(
      "Players",
      MessageOBJ.users.fetch().then((users) => {
        users.forEach((element) => {
          `${element.username}\n`;
        });
      })
    );

  fetchedMsg.edit(embed);
});
```

However, the bot displays `[object Promise]` in the Players category of the embed.

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.map()` instead of `Array.prototype.forEach()`

Comment: I tried, but that still give me [object Promise]

Comment: Can you try to `console.log(users)`?

Comment: i'm gonna but it i'm the quesqtion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm no expert in the discord api, however what you are experiencing is likely a problem with promises. The method returns a promise, which likely have the info inside it.

There are a few ways to solve this. My preferred way is to use [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('All players here !')
    .setDescription('Here\'s all of the players for this game')
    .addField('Players', await MessageOBJ.users.fetch().then(users => {
        users.map(element => 
            `${element.username}\n`
    )
    }))
```

As you can see, the [`addField`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-richembedmessageembed-constructor) needs the actual data, not the promise which returns the data.

To get this to work, you might have to mark your functions as [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Also, some of your inline functions also looks to have the wrong bracket formatting for what you are trying to achieve.

Likely the "end result" you are after is something like this:

```
MSG.messages.fetch({ around: GameID, limit: 1 })
    .then(async msg => {
        const fetchedMsg = msg.first();
        const MessageOBJ = fetchedMsg.reactions.cache.get("");
        const playerNames = await MessageOBJ.users.fetch()
            .then(users =>
                users.map(element =>
                    `${element.username}\n`
                )
            )
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('All players here !')
            .setDescription('Here\'s all of the players for this game')
            .addField('Players', playerNames)
        fetchedMsg.edit(embed);
    });
```

Comment: I tried, this gives me "undefined" into the discord embed

Comment: Here is a random article about the arrow function return rule: https://jaketrent.com/post/javascript-arrow-function-return-rules/

Comment: That's wasn't me for the down vote. And is there a way to use "if" into the users.map(element => ...) and the code will keep working fine ?

Comment: Yes, but then you must do use return. Eg `users.map(user => {if(user.something){return 'something'}else{return 'something else'}})`

Answer (score 0):

Try initiating the promise before you create the embed.

```js
function promise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3']);
  });
}

console.log(promise().then((result) => result)) // putting the promise inside
promise().then((result) => console.log(result)) // initiating it outside

// also, make sure to use `Array.map` instead of `Array.forEach`
promise().then((result) => console.log(result.forEach((user) => `${user}\n`)))
promise().then((result) => console.log(result.map((user) => `${user}\n`)))
```

```js
MSG.messages.fetch({ around: GameID, limit: 1 }).then((msg) => {
 fetchedMsg = msg.first();
 let MessageOBJ = fetchedMsg.reactions.cache.get('');
 MessageOBJ.users.fetch().then((users) => { // initiate promise
 const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('All players here !')
  .setDescription("Here's all of the players for this game")
  .addField(
   'Players',
    users.map((element) => {
     `${element.username}\n`;
    });
   })
  );
});
```